# How to search Alfresco for NOT NULL property?

Tags: alfresco

As I see, Alfresco has many languages for search. I need to find a documents with NOT NULL ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru property, how can I do that (any method)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the "IS NOT NULL" operator? Note, this query is not transactional, so you're effectively running this against the index.

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/intrans-metadata-query.html

Comment: It seems like CMIS can not access ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru and any other custom property. It said " Invalid column for ecmcndgostst:nd_gost_standards.ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru " but I have a custom type with this property

Comment: That is a different problem. With CMIS, you can only use properties (in query) that are members of the aspect you're selecting from. So, you need to do something like "select * from cmis:object join gg:myaspect where doc_name_ru", or select directly from "gg:myaspect".